# Adding a C wire to an Intertherm system

Tags: wiring, hvac, furnace, thermostat-c-wire

I am trying to add an Ecobee smart thermostat to an older Intertherm furnace and A/C. I have extra wires running to my thermostat, but can't figure out what to connect to in the furnace wiring. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Thermostat]

[image: Furnace]

[image: Wiring connections]

[image: Wiring diagram]

Answer (score 1):

### Use the existing black wire

From the wiring diagram for your unit, and the way your A/C appears to be wired, the light grey wire your unit provides for thermostat connection is the C wire.  This, in turn, is connected to the black wire in your thermostat cable.  So, simply use the black wire coming out of the wall at your thermostat as your C wire, and enjoy!